# Merge N lists of tuples of counts

Tags: python, list, algorithm, merge, tuples

Suppose I have N sorted lists of tuples `("val", "count_of_val")` (sorted lexigoraphically by the character "val"). I want to merge all lists and get the total counts, e.g.:

```
vec1: [("a", 10), ("b", 5)]
vec2: [("a" , 7), ("b", 10), ("c", 2)]
vec3: [("d", 2)]
vec4: []
...
```

Now I want to merge all of them in 1 big list (not a dictionary) to count total occurences:
`[("a", 17), ("b", 15), ("c", 2), ("d", 2)]`. I know that I can merge each vec one by one. I also think of N iterators through each list. But I was thinking if there is a faster solution.

Since lists are sorted, dictionary should be equivalent. So, is there are a mechanism which is better than what I am suggesting?

Comment: `collections.Counter()` seems fit

Answer (score 3):

accumulate values by key in a `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections

vec1= [("a", 10), ("b", 5)]
vec2= [("a" , 7), ("b", 10), ("c", 2)]
vec3= [("d", 2)]

c = collections.Counter()
for vct in (vec1,vec2,vec3):
    for k,v in vct:
        c[k] += v

print(c)
```

or use `update` which adds instead of replacing

```
for vct in (vec1,vec2,vec3):
    c.update(dict(vct))
```

you get:

```
Counter({'a': 17, 'b': 15, 'c': 2, 'd': 2})
```

convert back as tuples

```
>>> tuple(c.items())
(('c', 2), ('a', 17), ('b', 15), ('d', 2))
```

As a one-liner with `sum` (based on [Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef) comment)

```
c = sum((collections.Counter(dict(v)) for v in (vec1,vec2,vec3)),start=collections.Counter())
```

This is the most performant method, even if it involves creating some temporary dictionaries. It could be avoided with `zip` *if* all "keys" were present in each list but that's not the case here.

Performing lookups directly in the lists of tuples involves linear searches and therefore is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks! But I should have been more explicit. I aim to return a list of tuples. That would mean to cast this object. Which I think might be expensive

Comment: it's less expensive than finding the proper keys to add the values

Comment: Or `c = sum((Counter(dict(vec)) for vec in (vec1, vec2, vec3)), start=Counter())`

Comment: nice, added to answer with credit